# Diffraction of photons exhibiting random walking motion

Tags: optics, photons, diffraction

The explanation for the time it takes light to reach the surface of the sun is that photons take a very long random walk through the body of the sun until they emerge ay the surface 1000s of years later.

https://sunearthday.nasa.gov/2007/locations/ttt_sunlight.php

If a single or double slit could be fabricated to survive these conditions, would the photons on this random walk traveling through the slits display a diffraction pattern?

Edit: I removed the incorrect use of Brownian motion in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your link:

> Once you know, or assume, a typical distance between collisions, you also have to figure out how many steps the photon has to take to travel from the core to the surface.

Photons are quantum mechanical particles in the [mainstream physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), interacting with the electromagnetic fields of the particles and plasma  in the interior of the sun. Each successive  interaction of the original photon changes the frequency of the photon, so it is actually a different photon, as far as the elementary particle definition of the photon. The "random walk" of the link is a way to model how the original four momentum described for a photon ends up at the surface. Light, which is composed quantum mechanically out of zillions of photons is a different story, and it is light that can be slowed down to the numbers given.
(See [this reference](https://abcnews.go.com/Technology/story?id=99111&page=1) on "slow light" in the lab.)

You ask:

> If a single or double slit could be fabricated to survive these conditions, would the photons on this random walk traveling through the slits display a diffraction pattern?

To get an [interference pattern](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/slits.html#c1) one needs coherent photons of the same energy/frequency. This cannot be achieved in the "random walk" photons of the model of the interior of the sun.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Brownian motion. Based on your answer, it sounds like what is being described is how long it takes a perturbation traveling at the speed of light to reach the surface of sun from a point originating in its interior.

Comment: I removed the reference to Brownian motion in my original post. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveSaban and I removed the Brownian part from the answer, so you can edit your edit :).

Comment: "perturbation traveling at the speed of light "  The pertubation itself takes all that time, because it comes out as electromagnetic light which takes all that time to reach the surface. Photons themselves always travel at c, and their quantum sum makes up light, in a complicated way.

Comment: for classical EM to example quantum photons https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0606096 , or this file:///C:/Users/user/Downloads/1810.10852.pdf

Comment: Thanks for all the information. :-)